# How to delete a WORD in vim in insert mode

Tags: vim

Is there a way how to delete a whole WORD (e.g. from `vim path/to/some/file.txt` to `vim`) in insert mode?

To delete a word in insert mode the `C-W` shortcut works well. I got used to use `C-W` in bash too but bash actually deletes whole WORDs.

Now I'd love to be able to delete whole WORDs in insert mode. How can I achieve this in vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only `:help i_CTRL-W` for words, and `:help i_CTRL-U` for the entire line, but nothing for WORDs. You can easily define a custom mapping, though:

```
:inoremap <C-B> <Esc>"_dB"_s
```

Here's a more elaborate version, with better handling of corner cases:

```
inoremap <silent> <expr> <C-B>
\   col('.') == 1 ?
\       '<C-w>' :
\       col('.') >= col('$') ?
\           '<C-o>:normal! B"_d$<CR>' :
\           '<C-o>:normal! m"B"_dg`"<CR>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
:inoremap <silent> <C-w> <C-\><C-O>d<C-Left>
```

Comment: Whether this is correct or not is up to the OP. However, a short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.